# Check if a variable exists in external contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, addresses

kinda new to the development side of Ethereum. Been searching around for days but can't seem to find an answer for my specific case. I'm trying this challenge [here](https://ethernaut.gdshive.io/level/0xB99b3786E6C23EA8A04Ae8b5Cf3575770B8e03bB).

The problem is that I can't seem to access the variable in the Stamp contract using  `address(stamp).id()` when trying to check if the var Id exists as I get "TypeError: Member 'id' not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in address."

Referencing the validator [file](https://github.com/GovTechSG/SolidityCodingChallenge/blob/master/contracts/levels/StampCollectorValidator.sol), I can't create new contracts via the 'new' keyword to check that Id() exists as the validator is the one creating the contract at the particular address. As such, I need some way of accessing the variable of the external contract without using low level calls. This is why I haven't found answers on similar threads because in this instance, I can't modify the original Stamp or NotStamp contract.

Any pointers greatly appreciated. My attempt below. Thanks

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

interface IStampCollector {   
  function isCollected(address stamp) external returns (bool);   
  function collectStamp(address stamp) external; 
}

contract Stamp {   bytes32 public id;   uint public rarity;
    constructor(bytes32 _id, uint _rarity) public {
      id = _id;
      rarity = _rarity;   } 
    }

contract NotStamp {   bytes32 public notId;   uint public notRarity;
    constructor(bytes32 _id, uint _rarity) public {
      notId = _id;
      notRarity = _rarity;   } 
    }

contract StampCollector is IStampCollector, Stamp, NotStamp {

    bool public genuine;

    function isCollected(address stamp) public returns (bool) {
      require(address(stamp).id());
      genuine = true;
       }

      function collectStamp(address stamp) public {
       }
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
address(stamp).id()
```

To this:

```
Stamp(stamp).id()
```

Or better yet, to this:

```
Stamp(stamp).id
```

BTW, something is your design looks fundamentally wrong (or extremely suspicious):

Why does `StampCollector` inherit from `Stamp`?

Comment: Hey, thx for suggestions. I get a different TypeError where "no matching declaration found after argument-dependent lookup." for the `require` function. From my understanding, the above code should return that the .id exists if a contract has been initialized via the original `Stamp` or `NotStamp` contract.

I initially use the inheritance cause I thought that the contract needs to know what kind of value will be returned. Sorry if confusing, I'm still trying to wrap my head around the contract structures

Comment: @KaiShinAw: Well what exactly do you want to require about this id? It is not even a boolean variable, I just noticed. A `require` statement expects a boolean expression, which your `id` (without being compared to anything) is obviously not!

Comment: I guess that's the part which i'm still confused about as I just wanted to find out if `id` is not null (or >0 in the case of solidity). I can't use operators to compare `Stamp(stamp).id` to null/zero. Also, from the validator file, it seems like the address provided by argument `stamp` for the `function isCollected()` seems to be pointing to a contract where the contract `Stamp` has already been initialized. Appreciate your help on this as I might have just misunderstood fundamental parts of the language.

Comment: @KaiShinAw: Well, it sounds pretty obious that you don't need to inherit from `Stamp` and `NotStamp`. With regards to the comparison, I believe that `require(uint256(Stamp(stamp).id) > 0)` should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to compile using `require(uint(Stamp(stamp.id()) > 0)`

Thanks @goodvibrations for the pointer